# Trouble sending mail with PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a trouble trynig to send an email with PHPMailer, the code in the server is the next:

```
$Email = new PHPMailer();
$Email->isSMTP();
$Email->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$Email->SMTPDebug = 1;

$Email->SMTPAuth = true;
$Email->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$Email->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$Email->Port = 587;
$Email->Username = "noreply@MyMailService";
$Email->Password = "myPassword";


    $Email->setFrom("noreply@MyMailService", "EnterpriseName");
    $Email->Subject = $mensaje["destiny"];
    $Email->AddAddress($mensaje["destiny"], "");
    $Email->MsgHTML($mensaje["mensaje"]);

if(!$Email->send()){
    echo "Error sending: " . $Email->ErrorInfo;
}else{
 echo "E-mail sent";
}
```

So, I get this error when I test it with Postman:

*edit: Image Removed*

The mail host is the one provided for the hosting service, so I don't know, I'm not sure if the problem is with `$Email->Host` and how can I get that parameter?

Comment: Why should that be an issue with your `Host` setting? The error clearly states that the server does not accept a user/pass authentication.

Comment: Have you enabled SMTP within your google settings?

Comment: @MikelBitson no, because it's not an account of gmail. so I changed '$Email->Host="smtp.myhosting.com"' now I get another error related with SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.. thank you very much!

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova No problem! Yes, this is a certificate validation error- you can either bypass the check for the certificate verification (in your PHPMailer call) or you can install a valid ssl cert on the smtp server.